# How to move all files in a folder to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

if I:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/huser/Downloads/Weather2/* hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather
```

I will get

```
put: unexpected URISyntaxException
```

and if I:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/huser/Downloads/Weather2/ hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather
```

this will move all the files in Weather2 folder and the folder itself to `hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather`.

What I want is to move just the files inside Weather2 to `hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather` and not the Weather2 folder as folder

Comment: There is no issue with your command. Please check your cluster URI and destination path.

Answer (score 0):

To rename `/home/huser/Downloads/Weather2` to `/home/huser/Downloads/Weather`
Do:

```
hadoop fs -put /home/huser/Downloads/Weather hdfs://hname:9000/data/
```

Comment: Thanks Nizar. I already have Weather folder in under //hname:9000/data/ and it already contains files. I'm afraid by doing so I will lose the files already there. don't you think so?

Comment: the command hadoop fs -put /home/huser/Downloads/Weather hdfs://hname:9000/data/ will find that there is a Weather  forlder, it will not erase its content but it will merge with the old content

Comment: you can also use hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/huser/Downloads/Weather2/* hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you found solution to this. But this happens when you have files with space. Linux doesn't recognize spaces in their filenames. So, if you want to move those files, you first have to remove those spaces and then execute

```
hadoop fs -put /home/huser/Downloads/Weather2/* hdfs://hname:9000/data/Weather/
```

if this solves your query please rate this or you can provide further information if your files don't include spaces.